# Get offers on listings using eBay API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ebay-api

I'm looking to use the [eBay API](https://developer.ebay.com/develop/apis) to get information about listings and offers.

For a specific search query, I would like to return all matching listings. I believe this can be achieved using the [Browse API](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/buy/browse/static/overview.html).

However, I would also like to return any offers made by buyers on the listings. Is there a way to do this? I am looking to extract the offer's price, date and user especially.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.